# wall mounted switch to control a motor

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, shutters

I have a motorised shutter and I need to buy a in-wall switch to automatically stop when the shutter reaches the floor or the ceiling by only one push and not keep holding the switch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. More details would be helpful, e.g. the manufacturer and model of the shutter motor. (And, what's a "selling boy"; do you mean "ceiling"?)

Comment: The shutter motor (door opener) you buy should come with these attributes or have the facility to be programmed for this behavior.

Comment: correction yes the celling flour.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a controller circuit then, so a pulse will activate the motor going down and will deactivate when a limit switch has been activated or the button has been pushed again (using another button for going up). The design of such a circuit is out of scope on this SE.

When you do install such a controller circuit make sure the relays for driving the motor are rated for its power.

Comment: You'll also need all the safety sensors that typical garage doors have (obstruction detection, collision detection, etc.).

Comment: @Tester101 "shutter" can also mean window shutters or automatic curtains.

Comment: I agree, but the OP says "*reaches the floor or the selling*", which seems to imply something similar to a garage door (or guillotine if the proper safeties are not installed).

Comment: @Tester101 or a rolling curtain on a floor-to-ceiling window

Comment: You're right. In either case, you're also correct that designing the system is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you'll need a new motor & not a new switch. The new motor needs to be much like a Garage Door Opener's motor with similar circuitry, by having its own built-in & adjustable limiter switch. Then, you'll be able to press the switch once & walk away, for raising & lowering.